# crop pdf without losing annotations, using iText

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I have to crop a pdf of 26 pages, 24 and 25 being the form with annotations. after croping the 24 and 25th page the 24,25 pdf is signed and stored in the database. the problem is the croped pdf (24the, 25 pages) loses the annotations. the question is how to crop the pdf with annotations? should we read all the annotations, keep them, then crop the pdf and put the annotations back into the croped pdf? if so, how to do this, if not then other ways?

Answer (score 2):

A `PdfImportedPage` is really just the contents and resources of that page.  No marked content (save what's in the content stream which is useless without the info at the page level), no annotations, no bookmarks, etc etc.

BUT, if you use `PdfCopy.addPage( PdfImportedPage )`, `PdfCopy`s extra "plumbing" goes back and sucks out EVERYTHING from the original page.  Annotations, additional actions, that sort of thing.

If that's what you're already doing, perhaps you could share your code?

PS: "Cropping" means something entirely different in PDF.  You want to delete pages, not change their size.  But iText doesn't support that.  (?!  Wow,  That's a pretty big hole...  how embarrassing for us)